# How do i call a function from given two values in clojure one by one

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp

Hi i am new to clojure i have written this function and there are few errors in it. i have got one function called '**checkFunction**' it basically gets one paramtere and returns either true or false.

```
(defn getList [number1 number2]
  (loop for x from number1 to number2
    (recur (inc num) (if (checkFunction? x) (concat p [num]) p))))
```

i want the function above to take two paramters for example if i say **'get List 15 20'** it should call check function with **15 16 17 18 19 20** and if checkFunction returns **true** it should put that number in the **vector** and **return** it or **print** it. so far i have got onto this but i am struggling a bit.

Any help or right direction would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're trying to filter a range of numbers according to some predicate. (For the sake of the example I set your `check-function?` to return true for odd numbers.)

```
(defn check-function? [n]
  (odd? n))

(defn get-list [n1 n2]
  (filter check-function? (range n1 (+ 1 n2))))

> (get-list 15 20)
(15 17 19)
```

If you are also interested in how the loop-recur works, here's a version more like what you were trying to do originally. But I will say that one of the nicest things about clojure is that you rarely have to do this!

```
(defn get-list-2 [n1 n2]
  (loop [src (range n1 (+ 1 n2)) dest []]
    (if (empty? src)
      dest
      (let [n (first src)
            src (rest src)
            dest (if (check-function? n) (conj dest n) dest)]
        (recur src dest)))))

> (get-list-2 15 20)
[15 17 19]
```

Comment: I think he's trying to learn how to write a filter function, so using the built-in function doesn't help him learn.

Comment: That's a fair point, I probably should have asked that in a comment before posting.

Comment: @Barmar you are right as well but this will do as well

Comment: Updated with a version showing how loop-recur works.